# Referência System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Trabalhamos aki na empresa com o SNV com os projetos.

Certo dia o servidor deixou de funcionar, foi um trabalho para recuperar os projetos. Mas tem um projeto que está com um erro de referência com a seguinte mensagem:

> Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou uma de suas dependências. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.**

O projeto é em `ASP.NET MVC 3`. Já tentei baixar esse pacote pelo nuget, fazer referência pelo `web config`. Mas sem êxito. Alguém pode ajudar.

Comment: Uma vez tive isso também, tenta mudar na mão a versão do Razor, tipo: Version=2.0.0 pra ver se funciona. As vezes pode funcionar !

Comment: Tentei Erik Thiago, o projeto foi no visual studio 2010... vou tentar abrir o projeto no visual studio e tentar recuperar essa ddl

Comment: Exatamente. Tente isso. Mas tenta abrir o projeto em uma versão mais atual do VS pra ver se você consegue mudar na mão !

Comment: Deu certo aqui, muito obrigado Erik Thiago

Comment: Oopa que ótimo cara ! Fez o que te falei ou conseguiu arrumar de outra forma ? Se sim poste como resposta pra galera ! Se caso acontecer com alguém a pessoa sabe por onde começar ! :)

Answer (score 0):

No seu arquivo `Web.config`, verifique a seguinte entrada:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      ...
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      ...
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Repare que `oldVersion` é o intervalo de versões, enquanto que `newVersion` é a propriedade `Version` do seu Assembly. Verifique as entradas e teste novamente.